# Why is my script's regex having its backslash removed?

Tags: validation, plugin-gravity-forms, regex

One of my company's child themes requires customization. I am customizing using jQuery and have noticed in my function's regex (function lives in the "scripts" section of "Pages"--->My Page)

[image]

that backslashes are being stripped (definitely NOT as a result of one of my other functions). Needless to say I find this VERY annoying, since form validation (note: we use Gravity Forms and I need to validate this manually because of how my company uses mobile numbers, long story) of a phone number in the format (xxx) xxx-xxxx, which could more easily use this:

```
var jqnc = jQuery.noConflict();
var mobileNumber = jqnc("#input_1_41").val();

if (!mobileNumber.match(/^\([2-9][0-9]{2}\)\s[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/)) throwException();
```

now needs this:

```
 var jqnc = jQuery.noConflict();
 var mobileInput = jqnc("#input_1_41").val();
 if (mobileInput) {
    mobilePieces = mobileInput.split(" ");
    areaCode = mobilePieces[0].replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
    phoneNumber = mobilePieces[1];
 }

 if (!areaCode.match(/^[2-9][0-9]{2}$/) || !phoneNumber.match(/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/)) throwException();
```

Why is WP stripping the backslashes? I am assuming WP is using a stripslashes() somewhere but maybe this isn't it?

Comment: there is no "scripts" section native to WordPress, it is added by your theme or a plugin, so how that's being handled exactly is unanswerable without seeing the code responsible.

Comment: Hi @Milo, see my edit...a plugin must be responsible for this section then. OK, sounds like I must see how the plugin handles javascript